# Hover over radio button label and display an image

Tags: jquery

I have a number of html radio buttons and what I would like to do is when
the radio button label is hovered over display an image. The radio buttons are in groups
with each button having a unique id. The code below I think should work but it does not.

Does anyone have a better solution.

HTML CODE

```
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">
Name, text and logo
  <span class="rhidden">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_1" value="1">
  </span>
  <div class="place-image">
    <img src="../images/Name_logo.png">
  </div>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.rhidden {
  display: none;
}

.place-image{
  display:none;
}

div.place-image{
  width:326px;
  height:326px;  
}
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#RoomLevel_1').hover(
    function() {
      $('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
      $('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: why you have made place-image display none in css ? remove that css and try

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z7nfL38q/1/

Comment: CSS only solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7mwxotpq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are hovering on your input not on the label thats why it does not work, you can solve your problem like this if you don't want to select label directly

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let label = $('#RoomLevel_1').parent().parent();
    $(label).hover(
      function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
      },function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
  });
```

```css
.rhidden {
  display: none;
}

.place-image{
  display:none;
}

div.place-image{
  width:326px;
  height:326px;  
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">Name, text and logo<span class="rhidden">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_1" value="1">
   </span><div class="place-image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"></div></label>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your radio button is inside .rhidden which is hidden, so you can't hover over the radio so the logo is never shown.

> when the radio button **label** is hovered

So you don't want to attach your hover to the radio, you want to attach it to the label and can thus keep the radio itself hidden, likely for aesthetic reasons.

You can do this will CSS, without the need for jquery:

```css
.rhidden {
  display:none;  
}

.place-image {
  height:326px;
}

label.form-check-label .place-image {
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.6s all;
}

label.form-check-label:hover .place-image {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">
  Name, text and logo
  <span class="rhidden">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_1" value="1">
  </span>
  <div class="place-image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg" height='326px'>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed version works:

```js
$("#RoomLevel_1").hover(function(){
  $(".place-image").fadeIn('slow')},function(){$(".place-image").fadeOut('slow')}).hover()
```

```css
.place-image {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">
 Name, text and logo
 <span class="rhidden">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_1" value="1">
 </span>
 <div class="place-image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
 </div>
</label>
```